# The program that first gets a list of integers from input

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;  

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vector<int> vec;
        int n, num, t;
        Scanner myObj = new Scanner(System.in);

        int userName = myObj.nextInt();
        n = myObj.nextInt() ;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            num = myObj.nextInt();
            vec.push_back(num);
        }
     
        t = myObj.nextInt();
    
        for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
            if (vec[i] <= t) {
                System.out.println = vec[i]  + " ";
            }
        }
   
        return 0;
    }
```

Example:

Input:

5

50

60

140

200

75

100

Output:

50

60

75

Can anyone help me with these, please?

Write a program that first gets a list of integers from the input. The input begins with an integer indicating the number of integers that follow. Then, get the last value from the input, which indicates a threshold. Output all integers less than or equal to that last threshold value.

The 5 indicates that there are five integers in the list, namely 50, 60, 140, 200, and 75. The 100 indicates that the program should output all integers less than or equal to 100, so the program outputs 50, 60, and 75.

Comment: Unfortunately your question reads as though you want someone to write the code for you. Could you make an effort to write it in java and then ask if you get stuck?

Comment: Do you get errors when you run or compile? If so, would you please paste the exception trace or error into the question?

Comment: @NomadMaker reached end of file while parsing {

Comment: @sprinter I have edited the question can you now help me pleasee

Comment: @AngasteDandil The answer that has been posted gives a pretty comprehensive list of all the things you need to change in the code you posted. I suggest you start by taking that list of suggestions and then seeing if you get stuck. Honestly, if you want to learn the language, having someone provide a solution for you won't be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
vector<int> vec;
```

There is no `vector` class in the standard Java library, and in the Java versions I know you cannot make a collection of primitives (it may come). I suggest you use the `ArrayList` class (import `java.util.ArrayList` and use `Integer` as element type (conversion happens automatically). In Java remember to instantiate the list using `new`.

Then you will also need different methods from `push_back`and `[]`. Search for them or look them up in the documentation (link at the bottom):

```
int userName = myObj.nextInt();
```

This line does not belong in your program:

```
return 0;
```

The `main` method in Java cannot return anything, so delete this line.

PS There is a `Vector` class in Java, uppercase `V`. It’s outdated and not used in new code.

**Documentation link::** [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)